# Is it safe to generate an account with 256 coin flips?

Tags: security, accounts, private-key

Suppose one generates an account with the following procedure:

1. Flip a coin 256 times;
2. On a paper, write each heads as 1 and each tails as 0;
3. Convert the 256-bit string to hex by mapping each 4-bit sequence to a char from `0` to `F`;
4. Save that 64-character hex string to a file (say, `echo 'ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD' > priv.txt`);
5. Import that private key using `geth account import`;
6. Remove the file: `rm priv.txt`;
7. Store the private key in a safe place, offline.

Is to know if this procedure is safe or if is there any potential issue with it.

Comment: How do you know the coin flips really randomly? ;-)

Comment: @Viclib: it's a great way of generating a cold / paper wallet but it's going to be slow. A *Dungeon & Dragon* type dice with 16 sides shall be much faster (and it's kinda nerdier too) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is 100% secure, at least nothing you can be certain of.

Your procedure is a pretty good idea. I just played it through. Possible security implications:

1. The coin might not flip randomly enough. It's reported that some coins turn out more often heads than tails. Try a dice maybe (odds = 1, even = 0)?
2. If you use a machine to convert the binary number to hexadecimal, ensure it's offline and secure. Try to boot from a live medium before doing this.
3. The step saving it to disk (`priv.txt`) might leave a magnetic footprint on your harddisk. Again, boot from a live medium which operates in memory. But don't forget to backup your encrypted keystore.

I think it's easier and more safe than using geth directly to generate an encrypted keystore. Just make sure it's offline and operating in memory and well backed up.

Comment: +1... Note that when I boot from a Linux live CD I do it on a desktop PC (not a laptop) from which I've physically disconnected the harddisk and from which I unplug the network cable after having downloaded every dependency I need. So from the moment I unplug the network cable, the information I enter cannot be transmitted over the network nor written to the harddisk.

Answer (score 2):

While unlikely to flip so many heads in a row, it's still worth mentioning that [not all 256-bit numbers are valid private keys in Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-to-validate-a-private-key) and as explained [here:](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Range_of_valid_ECDSA_private_keys)

> Specifically, any 256-bit number from 0x1 to 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE BAAE DCE6 AF48 A03B BFD2 5E8C D036 4140 is a valid private key.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of that limit. Could also be relevant for [this question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6520/87).

Comment: @5chdn Your statement in that question "Now I see not every 256-bit number is a valid ECDSA private key for bitcoin." is what made me check this :)