# How can I generate a cold wallet completely offline WITH a random number seeded by me?

Tags: private-key, cold-storage, raspberry-pi

Requirements:

1) An account created on a raspberry pi that has never been connected to the internet ever.
2) A great private key on this account, that does not rely on any random number generator.
3) The ability to sign transactions on the pi (probably a QR code will be used to get them off the pi).

I found a great solution from Vitalik himself showing how to create the account and even sign a transaction: [python_cold_wallet_instructions](http://vitalik.ca/files/python_cold_wallet_instructions.txt). The line `eth.sendRawTransaction("<output of last line of code here>")` is what I would perform on a separate computer. All seems great except one thing:

The line `k = os.urandom(32)` implies using the random number generator. How can I avoid using the RNG? Isn't this a legit concern?

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Related & worth a read: [Is it safe to generate an account with 256 coin flips](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/989/87)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/ConsenSys/icebox - it supports offline generation of key and manual adding of random numbers.

The OS CSPRNG on Linux can be relied upon, as long as the computer has been doing a few things since first installing Linux (e.g. harddrive writes, mouse/keyboard inputs. Linux gathers entropy from such events into it's entropy pool, which is used when `os.urandom` is called.

Both `geth` and `eth` clients use the OS CSPRNG for generating keys, and this is widely considered as good practice as much effort goes into modern operating systems (Linux, Mac, Windows) secure random generators.