# Are there invalid private keys?

Tags: accounts, private-key

Private keys of Ethereum accounts are usually represented as 64-character hex strings. Will any such string work as a private key? Are there limitations on what the key could be? If not, I can just make a random string and use a `privateKey -> address` function and I have generated an account, as secure as any wallet generation library. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a random string yourself. 256 bit with two restrictions. Can't be zero and must be less than the order of the curve. Read more about it here [How to validate a private key?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-to-validate-a-private-key?rq=1).