# Why I can't import private key to metamask?

Tags: metamask, wallets, private-key, error, address.transfer

I'm new. Sorry for the question. Please, help me to understand why I can't import a similar private key to metamask:

FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE8AF48A04CBFD47E8CB0366361 how I can fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-to-validate-a-private-key/

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not a valid secp256k1 private key.

From [Secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) the order of the generator G is

```
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141
                                           |
```

Which is smaller that the private key

```
FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE8 AF48A04C BFD47E8C B0366361 
                                           |
```