Is there really 2^256 private key?
There are total 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336
Private key in Etherium. It is less than 2^256
Last private key of eth is fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140
Why not all ffffffff.......f  (i,e 64 no of f or 2^256)  ?

Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-to-validate-a-private-key

It is due to the properties of the secp256k1 elliptic curve used in the Ethereum protocol.
Private keys are integers in the range [1, n-1], where n is the order of the elliptic curve.
In the case of Ethereum, the order of the elliptic curve is 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141, so the largest private key is one less or 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140.
