# Can I use the same private key for Ethereum and Bitcoin?

Tags: accounts, private-key, bitcoin, cold-storage, secp256k1

Both Bitcoin and Ethereum private keys are usually a 256-bit number, isn't it possible to use the same private key for both Bitcoin wallets and Ethereum accounts?

For instance, the [Bitcoin wiki states](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#An_example_private_key):

> In Bitcoin, a private key is usually a 256-bit number (some newer wallets may use between 128 and 512 bits), which can be represented one of several ways. Here is a private key in hexadecimal - 256 bits in hexadecimal is 32 bytes, or 64 characters in the range 0-9 or A-F.
>
> ```
> E9 87 3D 79 C6 D8 7D C0 FB 6A 57 78 63 33 89 F4 45 32 13 30 3D A6 1F 20 BD 67 FC 23 3A A3 32 62
> ```

Which is (removed the whitespaces):

```
e9873d79c6d87dc0fb6a5778633389f4453213303da61f20bd67fc233aa33262
```

With [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) I generated the corresponding  public key for Ethereum:

```
0x60751Ab56d58781069b1C73064aD580dAde1F469
```

Now I see not every 256-bit number is a valid ECDSA private key for bitcoin. Can I use the same private key for Ethereum and Bitcoin? Is there a convenient way to generate both the ETH and BTC public key from any 256-bit random number?

This would be a cool way to store Ether and Bitcoin on the same account. Is it possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, both cryptocoins use the same elliptic curve SECP256K1.

Perhaps a better alternative is to use a [BIP32 wallet](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki). You have a master key that is not directly used for transactions, but it is used to derive child keys than can be used.

You can derive separate keys for bitcoin and ethereum. You will always be able to use the master key to sign transactions for both keys.

Comment: @5chdn check out [BIP 44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) for a wallet scheme that enables using multiple cryptocurrencies with the same HD private key

Comment: "Yes, you can"...but **how does one do so?** If I already have an appropriately backed up appropriately secured cold bitcoin wallet, how can I just reuse it for ethereum?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude If you have a [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) compatible wallet, you can generate keys using a path. For ethereum the more common path is `m/44'/60'/0'/0`, but there's no standarized path https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19055/what-is-the-difference-between-m-44-60-0-0-and-m-44-60-0 and  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/84.

Answer (score 6):

Self-answering my own question 4 years later: Yes!

I wrote an Secp256k1 implementation in Crystal: [github.com/q9f/secp256k1.cr](https://github.com/q9f/secp256k1.cr)

In that process, I implemented both key management for Bitcoin and Ethereum. The same keypair can be used to retrieve Bitcoin and Ethereum formatted addresses:

generate a compressed bitcoin mainnet address:

```
key = Secp256k1::Keypair.new

btc = Secp256k1::Bitcoin::Account.new key
btc.address
# => "1Q1zbmPZtS2chwxpviqz6qHgoM8UUuviGN"

eth = Secp256k1::Ethereum::Account.new key
eth.address
# => "0x224008a0F3d3cB989c807F568c7f99Bf451328A6"
```

The Github repository contains more examples. Interesting benefit: This way you could use the Bitcoin wallet-import format (WIF) for Ethereum accounts or even mini private keys.