# Deriving a Bitcoin Address from Ethereum Private Key

Tags: addresses, bitcoin, cryptography, keystore

There have been many answers about how to derive an Ethereum Address from a Bitcoin private key, but a curious problem has led me to ask how one would do the reverse. I'm sure it's possible because they have the same elliptic curve and key signature setup if but in a slightly different format. How would one go about generating a bitcoin address from an Ethereum private key?

Comment: Seems I found an answer that is suitable enough for my needs. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11535/374