# What is the difference between m/44'/60'/0'/0 and m/44'/60'/0'?

Tags: hd-wallets

When linking MyEtherWallet with a hardware wallet, there is a dropdown to select the HD derivation path. I understand that `m/44'/60'/0'/0` is the default. For some reason Ledger uses `m/44'/60'/0'`. I'm not sure what the missing `/0` means in the context of an HD wallet. What is the difference between the two derivation paths?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/84#issuecomment-292324521 for discussion trying to get all of the clients to standardize on a single derivation path (currently not very successful).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jaxx,MEtamask,...etc uses the BIP44 derivation.

from the BIP44 [specification](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), the HD derivation path is defined as :

```
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
```

But some wallets (e.g Ledger) chose an HD path of m/44'/60/0' which is **almost** BIP44, except the change path is not used.

just for information :

> Change
>
> Constant 0 is used for external chain and constant 1 for internal
>   chain (also known as change addresses). External chain is used for
>   addresses that are meant to be visible outside of the wallet (e.g. for
>   receiving payments). Internal chain is used for addresses which are
>   not meant to be visible outside of the wallet and is used for return
>   transaction change.

Comment: If the difference is only change addresses, why are the base (non-change) addresses generated by the two derivation paths different?

Comment: I think you need to read the bip32 to understand what's key derivation https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki and http://bip32.org

Answer (score 2):

The derivation path can be defined by every wallet independently, it's just a rule about **how they generate your wallet from a single master seed**. If you want to migrate your wallet to another device with your master seed, you may not see your original addressed (and balance) if it's using a derivation rule different from your original one.

The problem we face so many troubles in ETH wallets is that there hasn't been a standard for Ethereum Wallets to follow, some people want to follow BIP44 but the change index may be a little bit unnecessary under the account model.

Also for more information: Ledger is now switching to BIP 44 derivation path:

`m/44'/60'/x'/0/0`.

More detail from this thread: https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/MyCrypto/issues/2070