# Can't derive an account from a mnemonic phrase like in metamask?

Tags: metamask, private-key, public-key, bip32

I wrote a script that derivate keys on a given derivate path. I tested it [here](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/), and the results are for the path m/44'/60'/0'/0/0 matched. My goal is to generate a mnemonic phrase, and then derive an account from it, similar to the metamask account from this phrase. So, I am convinced that my script is working correctly (I also tested it on [test vectors](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#test-vectors) from the bip32 specification). However, when I generate a mnemonic phrase and then insert it into metamask, then my script and metamask give out different accounts. I use the derive path m/44'/66'/0'/0 according to the metamask specification, however, the accounts received are different. Maybe someone has encountered something like this, or I don't know something about the derivate of keys in metamask?

Comment: Can you share the source code? Any change in the derivation path will affect the calculated address. Try m/44'/60'/0'/0/0 or m/44'/60'/0'/0 (some wallets adds the extra /0 automatically). The derivation path has been standardized for several years https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19055/what-is-the-difference-between-m-44-60-0-0-and-m-44-60-0.