# Can Ethereum Contracts Store Bitcoin?

Tags: contract-development, bitcoin, secp256k1

I know that Ethereum and Bitcoin both you the [same underlying elliptic curve](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6520/can-i-use-the-same-private-key-for-ethereum-and-bitcoin), so I'm wondering, is it possible to store bitcoin in an Ethereum contract?

Answer (score 1):

**Sure!** As bitcoins are simply your ***"rights"*** to control the value of stored blockchain ledger entries, *practically speaking*, all you ever need is a **[private key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key)** to **store bitcoins.**

Example of a Bitcoin private key represented in **[WIF](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format)** format:
**`5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nFCDPsGHMGALCn1E`**
and its associated address:
**`1PsL2jSXpg8ojDdj9ZfVKib5vJKhmts4PP`**

In this format, an Ethereum contract could most certainly store a Bitcoin private key in a standard string variable *(or string array)*. The sky is really the limit in terms of applications for a Bitcoin private key database in a decentralized blockchain like Ethereum.

---

**WARNING!!!**

Considering that Ethereum is a **public** blockchain, similar to Bitcoin, the values that you store in its contracts are **also public information**. This could very likely result in the theft of your bitcoins by someone monitoring the network.

One possible remedy to this could be the use of **client-side encryption/decryption,** when storing/retrieving the private key value(s) in your Ethereum contract.

Comment: Thanks, @nyusternie. I guess I knew that that was possible. What I really mean to ask is there a way to do it in a more secure way similar to how contracts store ETH?